Show $65$ is an Euler-Jacobi pseudoprime to the base $b \iff b^{2} = \pm 1 \mod 65$
Say $(b,65) = 1$. I want to show that
$$65 \text{ is an Euler-Jacobi pseudoprime to the base }b \iff b^{2} = \pm 1 \mod 65$$
that is,
$$b^{(65-1)/2} = b^{32} \equiv \left( \frac{b}{65} \right) \mod 65 \iff b^{2} = \pm 1 \mod 65.$$
Ideally I want to show this as efficiently as possible in a way that can be done nicely by hand, i.e. don't just enumerate through all the cases.

Well, $65 = 5 \cdot 13$ so we need only care about the congruences mod $5, 13$ and can split up the Jacobi symbol using multiplicity in the denominator.
As $b^2 \equiv \pm 1 \mod 65$, we have $b^{32} \equiv 1 \mod 65$, so we want to show $\left( \frac{b}{65} \right) = 1$ for all $b$ coprime to $65$, equivalently $\left( \frac{b}{5} \right) = \left( \frac{b}{13} \right)$.
I'm not sure what the nicest way to do this might be, though. I know about Gauss' lemma that, for $p$ prime,
$$\left( \frac{a}{p} \right) \equiv (-1)^{\mu}$$
where $\mu = | \{ 1 \leq i \leq \frac{p}{2} : \langle ai \rangle < 0 \}$, where $\langle x \rangle$ is the unique integer such that $x \equiv \langle x \rangle \mod p$, $-\frac{p}{2} \leq \langle x \rangle < \frac{p}{2}$.
But how to actually calculate the value of $\mu$ for two different $p$, for arbitrary $b$, is something I'm unsure on how we may do.
To go the other way, I'm much less sure. If we have $b^{32} \equiv 1 \mod 65$, we certainly can't guarantee $b^{16} \equiv 1 \mod 65$, let alone $b^{2} \equiv \pm 1 \mod 65$.
How may I solve this "nicely"?

well $8^2 = 64 $

evidently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Jacobi_pseudoprime

if $b^{32}\equiv1\bmod65$, then since Carmichael $\lambda(65)=12$, it follows that $b^{8}\equiv1\bmod65$ so $b^{16}\equiv1\bmod65$
